# Replace a .net MAUI app with a Xamarin Forms App in Windows Store

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I created some time ago a small .net MAUI app which I sell in the Windows App Store.
The development was a pain since MAUI seemed not finished at all and the problems I had during development were almost unbelievable, although MS communicated that .net MAUI at that time was finished. Finally I got the app working (more or less).
Some problems however, I did not resolve at that time, since I thought, that MAUI will evolve and this will be fixed soon by Microsoft, since they were so unbelievable. Hover it seems, that this is not the case. For example, all buttons in the Windows UI have no visual effects assigned. If the user clicks on the button or hovers the mouse over a button, nothing happens - the button is like a static image, completely user unfriendly. I don't know if this is intentional, but I really don't want to waste my time to build such basic functionality myself.

Now I'm thinking to backtrack and create a new app with Xamarin Forms, which I known that it works fine. The creation of the app will be easy, since I can copy most of the logic and view models into the new app, but my question is, **if it is possible then to replace the MAUI app in the Windows Store through my new app and which parameters and values I must copy from the old MAUI project file to the new Xamarin Forms project file, so that the app store will accept the new app in place of the old failed MAUI app**.

Has someone done something like that and can point my in the right direction?

Comment: is this a cross platform app, or just for Windows desktop?

Comment: Its created as a cross platform, however, I only published it in the windows app store yet. Hence, app store compatibility of the new version is only necessary for the Windows app.

Comment: I absolutely feel with you. We're migrating from XF to MAUI and it's a horrible pain. We use .NET 7 for Android and iOS and MAUI seems far away from production level quality at the time of writing (Sept 2023).